# How to use futures with Akka for asynchronous results

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, actor, future

I am trying to write to multiple files concurrently using the Akka framework, First I created a class called MyWriter that writes to a file, then using futures I call the object twice hopping that 2 files will be created for me, but when I monitor the execusion of the program, it first populates the first file and then the second one (blocking /synchronously).

Q: how can I make the code bellow run  (none-blocking /asynchronously)

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.dispatch._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Promise }
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class my_controler {

}

object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  val myobj = system.actorOf(Props(new MyWriter), name = "myobj")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(50 seconds)
  val future2 = Future { myobj ! save("lots of conentet") }
  val future1 = Future { myobj ! save("event more lots of conentet") }

}
```

the MyWriter code:

```
case class save(startval: String)

class MyWriter extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case save(startval) => save_to_file(startval)
  }
```

any ideas why the code does not execute concurrently?

Comment: How `save` was defined?

Comment: ok let me edit my question to add that

Comment: Remember that hard disks don't like parallel access. They slow down - a lot. So don't write files in parallel if they are on the same hd. Also as others already mentioned, don't wrap communication with an actor in a future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you wrapping the call to `?` with an additional `Future`?  Ask (`?`) returns a `Future` anyway, so what you are doing here is wrapping a `Future` around another `Future` and I'm not surte that's what you wanted to do.

The second issue I see is that you are sending two messages to the same actor instance and you are expecting them to be running in parallel.  An actor instance processes its mailbox serially.  If you wanted to process concurrently, then you will need two instances of your `FileWriter` actor to accomplish that.  If that's all you want to do then just start up another instance of `FileWriter` and send it the second message.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, I was instantiating the same object, now that I created two different objects, it worked in parallel.  Many thanks.

Comment: One more questions, what if I want to start say 100 instance of the fileWriter , what is the best practice to do that?

Comment: For that scenario, I would suggest using a pooled router and then something like a round-robin or smallest-mailbox strategy.  Let the actors be long lived and sit behind the router which will distribute the messages to them.  Check out the docs on `Routers` for how to make this work, but from the creation point, it would look like this: `system.actorOf(Props[MyWriter].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(100)), "filewriter")`.  Docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/routing.html